# Instagram Analyze via API or something else

Tags: html, api, instagram, analytics, instagram-api

for a master thesis I need to analyze several Instagram profiles with more than 1000 posts each.

I need a list of the following things:
Post Type (Image, Multi Image, Video)
description
Likes
Comments (count)

Is there a way to do this with the Instagram Api or do you have another idea how this can work?

Thank you so much
Torben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. Not easily possible. Facebook has disabled this feature. What parts of this that still work will likely be disabled. You could try to scrape the profiles yourself from the public HTML Instagram webpages.

Using the developer console in Google Chrome and analyzing the network traffic I found the following URL that might be able to do some of what you want. Looks like calling the /graphql/query/ URL with a JSON object as a query parameter labeled: variables, along with a hash of some kind of that object. Not sure if you can call it on your own, but I've had success with other embedded URLs like this. The ID is the users ID which you can get from the HTML as well.

I hope it helps somehow.

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=76d9c5f9c2d88aa251ece9ea61fdc570&variables=%7B%22id%22%3A%225466275%22%2C%22first%22%3A12%2C%22after%22%3A%22AQCqBkaT0gZcgV1z9nfTgM3saTJi3cDRQoQy2YM4SdWNWyo3kdMTfCzWvuGcGRI9e1WpAIquMMG9jeuuXSe0TSMiQMPIL1ZmVimTMQ0dfrD_9Q%22%7D
```

Decoded that is:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_hash=76d9c5f9c2d88aa251ece9ea61fdc570&variables={"id":"5466275","first":12,"after":"AQCNhv_lxGd-nHBBaZb5kk3J4N-n058NgyCiWDnJ10rLc2V-YrVUvGsiuXr4NsMQ4QDzOLdjbTIVqoMpspJ69r-0s-PzOceis9J25o8P2BcjdA"}
```

Comment: I will try it this way. Maybe with a good Autoit Script I can do it.

Can you explain where you get the link? And currently you see only the first 12 posts. How can all of them be displayed or how can I load the next 12?

I almost forgot. Thank you so much!

Comment: In the Developer Console in Google Chrome, you can analyze the page and click on Network. It will show the network calls the page is making and the source code that is making it. Clearly the page is loading dynamically, and so you can see what URL is being called to load the images. For example if you scroll down on the users page, you will see in the console that when Instagram wants more more images it calls the above URL. While Facebook is limiting access, Instagram, unlike Facebook encourages public profiles. For example many people want their photos public for marketing purposes.

Comment: I didn't know anything about the "next_page" parameter at first but in the end it worked! You saved me a lot of time! Thank you